# Azure Cloud Shell Loading is delayed by around 20 minutes

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-shell

I am currently attempting to complete the AZ-204 training for the microsoft exam, however on multiple of the learning paths, when I go to load an azure cloud shell as part of the module, it can take upwards of 20 minutes to load.

[black screen displayed by shell while loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Hdih.png)

It will eventually complete, and allow access to the shell but it can be upwards of half an hour before it completes. Does anyone have any explanation for this? Does training accounts receive a lower priority? I'm fairly confident it cannot be a connection issue as I'm currently in a professional environment with a secure connection (as in I'm not working from home).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Nothing to do with account type .. check your internet connection once please. could be running bandwidth is low. Perform a speed test.

Comment: Ran a speed test - getting around 90 Mbps down and 48 Mbps up, lower than I actually expected, but I don't think it would be low enough to cause issues?

Comment: Hmm .. then raise a support ticket with Microsoft.

Comment: Likely you hit a peak in Microsoft Learning usage. Contact them.

Comment: Okay thank you for your help. I will contact microsoft regarding the issue.

Comment: @DonaghCarey Is this still an issue? Does this happen across browsers/devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure which browser you are seeing this issue with, but Azure Cloud Shell opening without bringing up the prompt is documented as a [known issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/support/troubleshooting) in Edge and Safari. Chrome is recommended as the browser to be used for running Learn exercises for the best user experience.

If feasible, you can also consider running Microsoft Learn exercises in [your own subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/support/use-your-own-subscription), if you're still unable to use the Sandbox environment for some reason. (Note that if you use your own subscription, you will be charged for any active resources).

If the issue persists, you can [report feedback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/support/troubleshooting#report-feedback) at the bottom of each unit in a Learn module. This will allow you to send the teams communication about the content or Learn experience.

Comment: I've now moved over to my own subscription and the terminals are a lot quicker to load.  Thanks so much for your help.